# Citation and Bib not showing up in PDF - Texmaker/MikTex

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, cross-referencing

My references aren't showing up at all when I try to complile my PDF. I've already compiled in the following manner

```
pdflatex file.tex && bibtex file.aux && pdflatex file.tex && pdflatex file.tex
```

Here is what the document code looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel, soul}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colon]{natbib}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{wasysym} %allows some extra symbols (e.g., male & female symbols)

\usepackage{caption} % for centering caption
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}



\def \tabpath {../Tables/}
\def \figpath{../Figure/}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % define a column type that will be centered
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % define a column type that will be left-aligned (gets rid of awkwardly big spaces between words)
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % define a column type that will be right-aligned (gets rid of awkwardly big spaces between words)

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} %footnotes
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.35cm}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{3.5mm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear, style=authoryear ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}


\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3.33em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3.33em}

\singlespacing
\begin{document}

some text
\newpage \clearpage

\singlespacing

\nocite{*}
\setlength{\bibsep}{8pt}
\bibliographystyle{aer}

\bibliography{migration_bibTEST}


\pagebreak
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Sorry for the long preamble, I'm not sure what is necessary for you all to know or not.
Here below is my bib:

```
@article{naidu_nyarko_wang_2016, title={Monopsony power in migrant labor markets: Evidence from the United Arab Emirates},
volume={124}, DOI={10.1086/688877}, number={6}, journal={Journal of Political Economy}, author={Naidu, Suresh and Nyarko, Yaw and Wang, Shing-Yi},
year={2016}, pages={1735–1792}}
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be? I've tried fixing typos and changing the format of the bib file many many times. Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You used `\bibliography{migration_bibTEST}` in your preamble, instead of `\addbibresource{migration_bibTEST.bib}`

Comment: Your exmple isn't really very reasonable, over 90 lines almost none of them relevant to your question.  "Sorry for the long preamble, I'm not sure what is necessary for you all to know or not" isn't really an excuse, it would have been easy for you to test your example before posting, and deleting every line not needed to show the problem.

Comment: Hi @Bernard! This produces a new error- undefined control sequence. Why may this be the case?

Comment: @AdiJahic: noidea. \addbibresource is the normal syntax with biblatex. Maybe delete all the auxiliary files first.

Comment: I'm not sure why Bernard is suggesting biblatex commants. Biblatex is commented out in the example document, and natbib is loaded, so `\bibliography` is the correct command. (Or has it changed since being posted?) Your document works fine for me as is, so I don't know what problem you're having. Can you post the `.blg` file somewhere?

Comment: Frabjous- interesting that it works for you. How would I post the blg file? Ill try to add it to the question,

Comment: Also @frabjous - what compiler do you use?

Comment: I used exactly the pdflatex/bibtex command you posted in your question. The second page of output looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/pDg5SUS). If it doesn't fit in the question, you could post your .blg at a pastebin site and post a link. E.g., here's my [file.log](https://pastebin.com/TUjHyQBU) and [file.blg](https://pastebin.com/1vVmQvX2) if you want to compare version numbers.